# Exponential number generator sometimes gives "weird" results

Tags: c++, random

I am building a simulation in C++ and I have an exponential generator to make the burst times of the processes.

Usually it returns values as such: 3.14707,1.04998. But frequently 1/10 occasions such numbers turn out: 2.64823e-307

This is the code of the generator (I am using `srand ( time(NULL) );` at the beginning of the program):

```cpp
double exponential(float u)
{
   double x,mean;
   mean = 10;
   // generate a U(0,1) random variate
   x = rand();
   u = x / RAND_MAX;
   return (-mean * log(u));
}
```

And this is how I assign the values. The `while` part inside is my effort to get rid of such values but it didn't work:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < nPages; i++)
{
    index[i] = i;
arrival[i]= poisson(r);
burst[i]=exponential(u);
while (burst[i]<1 || burst[i]>150)
    {
        cout<<"P"<<i<<endl;
        burst[i]=(burst[i-1]+burst[i+1])/2;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the role of `float u` in `double exponential(float u)`.
you are overwriting it is value.

Comment: What if `rand()` returns `0`? ([`log(0)` returns `HUGE_VAL`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log))

Comment: What if `rand()` returns `RAND_MAX`, or close to it? You return `0` or close to it.

Comment: Actually     float u does nothing its just used to generate the number and nowhere else.

Comment: how can i solve/check these 2 issues about rand? could i use an if structure inside the function?

Comment: Can you use C++11's RNGs?

Comment: no i cannot :S, its my thesis and my proffesor preferred this way :S

Comment: What is burst and is using burst[i-1] sensible when i is 0?

Comment: Your professor prefers buggy implementations of standard random distributions? Fire your prof :) (half-joking, only)

Comment: burst are the times that the processes must remain in the cpu to be completed. No it is not sensible but it is an effort. I have also tried ree-initializing it assigning value to it again but didnt work

Comment: `srand` and `rand()` are NOT C++ use `#include <random>` and C++11

Comment: What is so weird about `2.64823e-307` (it's just a very small number)? What is the required range of output values for `exponential`? Is it [1.0, 150.0]?

Comment: 1) The inversion algorithm you're using works for U(0,1)'s, not for U[0,1]'s. 2) Do yourself a favor and don't use `rand()`. 3) Do yourself another favor and use `double`s rather than `float`s. 4) Who the heck is your advisor, and where are you writing your thesis?

Comment: @DyP The range of exponentials is 0 to infinity.  Since he wired the mean to be 10, 2E-307 is possible it shouldn't be happening 1/10th of the time.  In fact, the 10th and 90th percentiles should be 1.05 and 23.03, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you use the C library instead of the C++ library ??

```
std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine gen(rd());
std::exponential_distribution<double> dist(lambda);

double x = dist(gen);
```

Comment: What if he doesn't have C++11 support?

Comment: i will results to this if i cant make anyting else,  thank you

Comment: @LihO then he should have said so. The question mentions C++ and the current standard (2011) is two years old and mostly implemented by (the current versions of) most compilers. Deliberately restrictcing oneself to the 2003 standard is non-sensical.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of burst is nPages, then

```
for (int i = 0; i < nPages; i++)
{
    //...
    burst[i]=(burst[i-1]+burst[i+1])/2;
}
```

will step outside its bounds, so you are likely to end up with nonsense.
You need to think about what is required at the edges.

As far as the comments about `rand` go [rand considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) is worth a watch. In your case taking log of 0 is not sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Using your `exponential` function copied verbatim, I cannot reproduce the error you describe.  Issues with the PRNG cranking out either 0 or `RAND_MAX` should only show up one time out of `RAND_MAX` apiece, not 10% of the time.  I suspect either a buggy compiler, or that what you have shared is not the actual code that produces the described problem.